# How to create a JSONObject for nested json

Tags: java, json

I am unable to create a json object for nested json.

I can create json objects for basic json.
I am unable to add further fields.

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {

        jsonObject.put("name", "new name");
        jsonObject.put("description", "new election");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is my json:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "candidates": [
    "string"
  ],
  "ballotVisibility": "string",
  "voterListVisibility": true,
  "startingDate": "2019-07-05T20:09:23.311Z",
  "endingDate": "2019-07-05T20:09:23.311Z",
  "isInvite": true,
  "isRealTime": true,
  "votingAlgo": "string",
  "noVacancies": 0,
  "ballot": [
    {
      "voteBallot": "string",
      "voterEmail": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to have `POJO` and then transform them using `gson`. This kind of JSON object creation is error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("voteBallot", "string");
    map.put("voterEmail", "string");
    try {

        jsonObject.put("name", "new name");
        jsonObject.put("description", "new election");
        jsonObject.put("candidates", new String[] {"new String"});
        jsonObject.put("ballotVisibility", "string");
        jsonObject.put("voterListVisibility", true);
        jsonObject.put("startingDate", LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        jsonObject.put("ballot", new Map[]{map});
        System.out.println("jsonObject = " + jsonObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it's not all the fields but it's all the different types hope it helps.
Output:

```
{  
   "ballot":[  
      {  
         "voteBallot":"string",
         "voterEmail":"string"
      }
   ],
   "candidates":[  
      "new String"
   ],
   "ballotVisibility":"string",
   "name":"new name",
   "voterListVisibility":true,
   "description":"new election",
   "startingDate":"2019-07-05T22:34:58.750Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a new `JSONObject` then append it to the parent object with its new name.  An example is shown below appending the `ballot`:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject ballot = new JSONObject();
ballot.put("voteBallot","string");
ballot.put("voterEmail","string");

jsonObject.put("name", "new name");
jsonObject.put("description", "new election");

jsonObject.put("ballot", ballot);  //Append the other JSONObject to the parent one

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

**Output(with some formatting):**

```
{
"ballot":
     {
     "voteBallot":"string",
     "voterEmail":"string"
     },
 "name":"new name",
 "description":"new election"
}
```

You can also use `JSONArray` instead and append it in the same manner.

Comment: For nesting a map, this answer is correct and makes sense.  However, the question shows "Ballot" as an array of maps. So this answer isn't completely correct.  To create an array use the `JSONArray` object.  Something like this:
`JSONArray arrBallot = new JSONArray();
arrBallot.add(ballot); // populated as shown in the answer
jsonObject.put("ballot",arrBallot);
`